# apache camel component to consume messages from pravega

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

is there an any Apache Camel component, similar to the Kafka component, that allows me to consume messages from [Pravega](https://github.com/pravega/pravega).

Comment: Greetings ! i provided an answers please consider to upvote or accept it if it address the solution otherwise feel free to leave comment, here to help.

Answer (score 0):

> Apache camel component to consume messages from pravega ?`enter code here`

You can use the [Camel-Pravega](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/external/apache-camel.html) component, which provides a Camel endpoint for reading and writing data to Pravega streams,  you can do this in your Camel configuration file or in your Camel route definition.

```
public class CamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("pravega://tcp://localhost:9090/scope-name/stream-name")
            .process(e -> {
                // Process the message
                ...
            })
            .to("log:my-logger");
    }
    
    ...
}
```

This route consumes messages from the `scope-name/stream-name` stream in the Pravega cluster using the Pravega endpoint then processes the message in the process block, and logs the message using the Camel log component.
Afterward you can start the Camel context and it will automatically consume messages from the Pravega stream, some thinglike

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
context.addRoutes(new CamelRoute());
context.start();
Thread.sleep(5);
context.stop();
```

Which we configured the lifetime to 5 second.